# Validations for the at least two from 4 values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, conditional-statements

Actually I am new to the `javascript` I have used `disabled` here ,

Now In this ,

```
!props.updatedOption1 || !props.updatedOption2 || !props.updatedOption3 || !props.updatedOption4
```

I do have this four conditions ,

Now, what I want is that, `if two are filled then it should be enabled`, right now what happens is that four of them are `compulsary`.

So,I tried with the `&&` condition but it was getting  too lengthy.

So, can any one suggest me  different solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could count the options with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
var options = ['updatedOption1', 'updatedOption2', 'updatedOption3', 'updatedOption4']


if (options.reduce((s, k) => s + !props[k], 0) >= 2) {
    // ...
}
```

Or you could use a closure for counting and exit early if the condition match

```
var options = ['updatedOption1', 'updatedOption2', 'updatedOption3', 'updatedOption4']


if (options.some((c => k => !props[k] && !--c)(2))) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
['updatedOption1', 'updatedOption2', 'updatedOption3', 'updatedOption4'].filter((option) => 
props[option]).length >= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make them into an array, then `filter` out the false values and see if the length of the resulting array is two or longer. Since two options are `true` below, it'll evaluate to Enabled:

```js
var props = {
  updatedOption1: false,
  updatedOption2: true,
  updatedOption3: true,
  updatedOption4: false
};

var options = [props.updatedOption1, props.updatedOption2, props.updatedOption3, props.updatedOption4];
options = options.filter(e => e);
if (options.length >= 2) {
  console.log("Enabled!");
} else {
  console.log("Disabled!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could treat `bool` values as `int`:

```
if((props.updatedOption1 + props.updatedOption2 + props.updatedOption3 + props.updatedOption4) <= 2)
{
  //...
}
```

I used `<=2` here because you used `!props.updatedOption` in the example.

Answer (score 0):

If updatedOption1-4 are the only properties of `props` then you can do this:

```
const isValid = Object.values(props).filter(p => p).length >= 2;
```